# mysql excute() method give false value even execution happen correctly

Tags: java, mysql

boolean done =state.execute(query)   value of done variable is false even query execution happen correctly and database update correctly.please help me to find what happen

```
public boolean update(ProductDataModel productDModel) throws SQLException {
        Statement state;
        String query;
        boolean done;
        DataConnectionControl data_connection = new DataConnectionControl();

        state = null;
        Connection con = data_connection.GetConnection();
        state = con.createStatement();
        query = "update product set  pName='" + productDModel.getPName() + "', pCategory='" + productDModel.getPCategory() + "', pDescription='" + productDModel.getPDescription() + "', quantity=" + productDModel.getQuantity() + "  where productID=" + productDModel.getProductID();
        done=state.execute(query);
        System.out.println(done);
      return done;
    }
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [Statement.execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: just read it  :D  i got the point :D

Answer (score 1):

Read the Javadocs of [`Statement#execute(String query)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)):

> Returns `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if it is an update count or there are no results

and this is an update statement.

Consider using `Statement#executeUpdate()` instead, which returns the number of updated rows.

Answer (score 0):

Correct if update done successfully then it will return you false otherwise true.

refer [This](http://www.java2novice.com/jdbc/execute-method/)